# Loading a a saved Map into native MapView

Tags: android, dictionary, overlay

I wish to load a saved Google map into a `MapView` activity. For example here is a [map](http://maps.google.co.uk/maps/ms?ie=UTF8&hl=en&msa=0&msid=208098337405418082800.0004649ef324c7b2f077a&z=8) that I have created in a browser. Is there a way to see this map with overlays etc in a `MapView`?

I know that I can view the map in `WebView` but the user experience is not as good as the native android `MapView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to see this map with overlays etc in a MapView?

No, sorry.